# Hive with Hbase Query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have done the integration with Hbase

> Version used for setup
>
> Hbase-0.98
>
> Handoop-2.5
>
> Hive-0.14

When I started the Query with Order by Clause The Query is mentioned below

> Query : select * from hbasehive_table order by key;

I am getting below error , but Jar file is present in the respective folder

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   /home/hadoop/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin/lib/hbase-server-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
    sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.90.1-cdh3u0.jar  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/
```

2)CLOSE HBASE AND HADOOP USING FOLLOWING COMMOND

```
      /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
      /usr/lib/hbase/bin/stop-hbase.sh
```

3) RESTART HBASE AND HADOOP USING COMMOND

```
     /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
     /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/start-hbase.sh
```