# hbase mapreduce file not found exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, filenotfoundexception

I have installed hadoop 2.4.1 and hbase 0.98.8 in 2 machines. When I run an hbase mapreduce job I get the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://pc1/opt/hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2/lib/hbase-server-0.98.8-hadoop2.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at thesis.test2.run(test2.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at thesis.test2.main(test2.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I can run hadoop mapreduce jobs and simple hbase jobs without any problems. The code I m trying to run is an example that is supposed to run.

Comment: Check this out 
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374810/my-cdh5-2-cluster-get-filenotfoundexception-when-running-hbase-mr-jobs/27501623#27501623
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111241/hive-with-hbase-query

Comment: already seen these. didn't help. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Please provide "jps" output.
Because it seems like your hbase is not working , hopefully the problem will be with zookeeper

Comment: root@pc1:/opt/hadoop-2.4.1# jps  
3975 NameNode  
6331 HQuorumPeer  
4421 ResourceManager  
4085 DataNode  
4528 NodeManager  
7186 Jps  
6430 HMaster

Comment: i can run simple hbase jobs. i can create tables and put items in them

Comment: are you able to create table and put items in hbase using mapreduce or directly using terminal window of hbase ?

Comment: directly and with java. not mapreduce

Comment: Then I am pretty much sure that your hbase is not well not configured.Please follow any good tutorial to setup hbase.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact problem. You have to add the hbase library path to the **.bashrc** file. Add the lib folder in hbase to the CLASSPATH. 
Also, add the classpath of hbase to HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

Your **.bashrc** file should contain the following:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase mapredcp`

export CLASSPATH=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/*
```

Note: The CLASSPATH should point to the lib folder of your hbase installation folder. Use the following to compile and run your java code.

```
javac Example.java
java -classpath $CLASSPATH:. Example
```